# Why does Javascript say "callback is not a function" in setTimeout when the wait value is much lower?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I have written a basic job runner in javascript (utilizing some JQuery too, but that's another story for another day) and I came across this queer Issue:

The method I run to wait for all jobs to complete:

```
$.getAllProducts = function(callback){
      $.getProductDetails('|ALL|', function(allProductsResult){ //intentionally
          var objAllProducts = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(allProductsResult));
          var objProductsBuiltUp = {};

          var productLength = objAllProducts.length;
          $.totalJobs(productLength);

          var processed = 0;
          $.completedJobs(processed);

          $.each(objAllProducts, function(i,v){
              $.getProductDetails(objAllProducts[i].ProductCode, function(result){
                $.mergeShallow(objProductsBuiltUp, JSON.parse(JSON.parse(result)));
                processed++;
                $.completedJobs(processed);
              });
          });

          $.wait(0, false, function(isDone){ //allow at least 50ms wait time, otherwise this confuses javascript into thinking there are no callbacks
            if (isDone){
              callback(objProductsBuiltUp.ProductComponents);
            }
          });
      });
    }
```

The handlers for the job

```
    $.checkProgress = function() {
        return $.jobs === $.completed;
    }

    $.totalJobs = function(total) {
        $.jobs = total;
    }

    $.completedJobs = function(completed) {
        $.completed = completed;
    }

    $.wait = function(timeout, debug, callback) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (debug) {
                console.log($.completed + " / " + $.jobs + " = " + ($.completed / $.jobs * 100) + "%");
            }

            if ($.checkProgress() == false) {
                $.wait(timeout, debug);
            }
            callback($.checkProgress()); // <-- complaining one

        }, timeout);
    }
```

This is the key-point code for my little job runner, other methods will call `$.totalJobs()` to set the amount of jobs that need to be performed (normally based on amount different calls need to be made to an API In my scenario), and `$.completedJobs()` - which is called when the payloads are returned in the API handler's callbacks

The issue is, when I set my "Waiter" to 50ms, I don't get any errors whatsoever, and the method performs as per expected.

When I set it to low values like 5ms, 1ms, 0ms, It tells me:

> "xxxxx.helpers.js:48 Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function"

Anyone have a wild-flung theory why this would occur? it is, afterall, only a glorified `setTimeout`.

(P.S. In response to why I use JQuery global methods and variables to store info is to make using Meteor easier on myself knowing it's loaded into 1 place - this is the platform I am developing on at the moment.)

**EDIT** was better for me to add the whole method where the callback is run

Comment: in the line `callback(objProductsBuiltUp.ProductComponents);` where/how is callback defined?

Comment: I guess I should add that.

Comment: I am using latest version of Chrome, running on Latest Version Meteor JS

Comment: ok, so now, where/how is `getAllProducts` called?

Comment: Whose calling $.getAllProducts ? im asuming you call it like this $.getAllProducts(SomeString) instead of $.getAllProducts(callbackFunction);

Comment: "*`JSON.parse(JSON.parse(result)))`*" - uh what?

Comment: ^^^ I guess that's what the `// intentionally` comment is referring to?

Comment: @Bergi it's a bug in our API returning some dud JSON... double parsing helps... for now. 

@JaromandaX $.getProductDetails accepts 1 parameter and has 1 callback. Sig: `  $.getProductDetails = function(productCode, callback) {`

Comment: @squint yes... yes it is. I just marked it that I don't go back thinking if I actually thought that was a great idea, just marks that I know something is funky on that line. but that's outside the issue i'm having now.

Comment: @Krohn - so you say, but are you calling `getAllProducts` with a single argument that is a function? (not sure why you described the `getProductDetails` in response to my question about `getAllProducts`

Comment: got confused, but it's really complicated. $.getAllProducts gets called in a `$timeout` in angular. isn't really relevant to the question, the question was why I got the exception - and that's because I forgot to forward the callback in the recursive call I'm doing. wow, I need to go to bed, 18 hours straight coding is making everything so bad.

Comment: @Krohn: Given that you're in a browser -> use chrome debugger to step through the code to figure out when `callback` is lost, now get some rest ;-p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're not passing a callback here:

```
$.wait = function(timeout, debug, callback) {
    //code here
    if ($.checkProgress() == false) {
        $.wait(timeout, debug); // === $.wait(timeout, debug, undefined);
    }
    callback($.checkProgress()); // <-- complaining one

}, timeout);
```

so if `$.checkProgress()` is false, you're calling `$.wait` recursively only `callback` is `undefined`...

At first glance, I think what you wanted to write there was:

```
$.wait(timeout, debug, callback); // pass callback argument to inner call
```

But then obviously, you wouldn't want to invoke the callback multiple times:

```
$.wait = function(timeout, debug, callback) {
    //code here
    if ($.checkProgress() == false) {
        $.wait(timeout, debug, callback);
    } else {
        callback($.checkProgress());
    }

}, timeout);
```

The reason why the line you marked as "the complaining one" is in fact complaining is because it's the recursive call. `$.checkProgress` evaluated to false, the `$.wait` function is invoked (this time, `callback` is undefined), and that continues until `$.checkProgress() === false` evaluates to false. Then, `callback` (which is `undefined`) will get invoked in the inner call.

---

This issue started appearing when the interval was reduced down. That makes sense, because you're only recursively calling `$.wait` if the jobs hadn't been completed. The higher the timeout/interval, the greater the chance the jobs were completed the first time around.

By reducing the interval, you arrived at a point where `$.wait` got invoked *before* the jobs had finished, and you entered the `$.checkProgress() === false` branch, calling `$.wait` without passing the callback (essentially losing a reference to it).

By the time the jobs had completed, you were trying to invoke `callback`m which was set to `undefined`.

Comment: I haven't thought of that and got stuck in the ratrace trying to figure out why it throws it when I set the timeout to  lower intervals (the 50ms part) vs. higher intervals (5 ms and down). 

You're solution works and is explained concisely, though, what's the riddle of why the intervals had effect on why I'm getting the exception?

Comment: @Krohn: The shorter the intervals, the more likely it becomes the jobs haven't completed. Ergo: the more likely it becomes you'd start recursively calling `$.wait`, and not passing the callback. If the interval provided enough time for the jobs to complete, you never performed the inner call, and always used the callback rightaway

Answer (score 3):

In

> ```
> if ($.checkProgress() == false) {
>     $.wait(timeout, debug);
> }
> ```

you're not passing through the `callback` parameter, so in the "recursive" call it will be `undefined` and you're getting the exception you posted. Make it

```
if ($.checkProgress() == false) {
    $.wait(timeout, debug, callback);
//                         ^^^^^^^^
}
```

Comment: DOH!. ok giving it a shot.

Comment: @Krohn: Updated my answer: don't forget not to invoke the callback more than once: add an early return or an `else`